# UIPageControl does not show current page

Tags: ios, xcode, uipagecontrol

Page Control indicator does not follow with scroll view.I tried both:   -and nothing works.. what am I doing wrong?

```
-(void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

CGFloat pageWidth = self.scroller.frame.size.width;

int page = floor((self.scroller.contentOffset.x - pageWidth/2)/ pageWidth)+1;
self.pageControl.currentPage=page;

}

-(void) scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
   int page = scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width;

self.pageControl.currentPage = page;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to specify your currentPage within the method `-(void) scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView`

Comment: in my description i specified that i tested both..(individually). any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: can u be more specific about "This doesn't work" - do u see an update of the page control at least when you scroll your view?

Comment: so the scrollViewDidScroll method is not called? you need to set your controller as the delegate of your scrollview: you probably missed this part

Comment: @interface FifthViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate> {
    UIPageControl *pageControl;
    UIScrollView * scroller; i did not missed that.. i honestly dont know whats wrong..

Comment: You need this line to make within your UIViewController: scroller.delegate = self; declaring UIScrollViewDelegate is not enough